# Equivalent of VS 2019's ASP.NET Core Web Application in VS 2022

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

A [book I have purchased](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08KYKNGCC) has its material based on Visual Studio 2019.

Its very first project is of type *ASP.NET Core Web Application*. One should then pick an *ASP.NET Core with React.js* in the subsequent step.

At first, I downloaded and installed the latest version of VS, the 2022 Community version, to see that no project under this name could be created.

So, **I'm wondering what the equivalent of an ASP.NET Core Web Application is in 2022**. The few ones I tried do not have a `Main` method in the `Program.cs` file, which is what the book is instructing me to check. So, I suspect that it is not the correct version.

(I actually installed VS 2019, but then I could not find the Core libraries in the create project dialog, so I'm back on 2022 which is the latest version and more reliable.)

Comment: Mine is showing it... but it's one-step.  New Project, choose ASP.NET Core with React  (need to scroll down a bit to find that...)  There are also some pulldowns at the top used to filter, so be sure it's set to "All languages, All platforms, and All Project Types"

Comment: @pcalkins you're right. I also see that there are two variants of it: one with JavaScript and the other with TypeScript. But the thing is, I don't see a `Main` method in the `Program.cs` as it says in the book (there is a `Run` method instead). So, I don't think these are the same type of project, This is expected. There are three years between these two versions. A lot has happened.

Comment: after .net-core 3.1 they migrated to a new "minimal hosting model".  This combines Startup.cs and Program.cs into a single file.  You can still use the old model in the newer .net if you like.   Be aware that you basically have two projects in one.  One is for the back-end, and one is for the front-end (react page intitialy served from the back-end, but run in the browser).   If you want to follow your book, see if they include a chapter on Typescript, if not use the Javascript version of the project.  (Typescript will be a better way to go... but more learning to do)